# Running multiple processes in each iteration of loop in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpython

I have two functions `func_1` and `func_2`. They both take an array of integers as input.

I have a loop that creates arrays of length `i` in the `i`th iteration.

I have two predefined lists `list_1` and `list_2` intended to store the outputs from the functions at each iteration.

Thus, for each iteration I want to run the two functions parallelly with the array created in the iteration as the input. CPython doesn't have true multithreading, so I'm using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

I want to create two separate processes for each of the functions at each iteration of the loop, and `close` the processes by the end of the iteration.

I have so far tried using `Pool` and `Process`. I can't get them to populate `list_1` and `list_2`, even by sending the two lists as arguments to the respective functions and appending the result to them, in the functions.

How do I achieve this? Explanations will be appreciated.

Here is what I've done that's not working:

```py
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for input in range(n):
    arr_1 = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(input)]
    arr_2 = list(arr_1)
    proc_one = mp.Process(target=func_1, args=(arr_1, list_1)
    proc_two = mp.Process(target=func_2, args=(arr_2, list_2)
    
    proc_one.start()
    proc_two.start()
    
    proc_one.join()
    proc_two.join()
    
print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

And here are the two worker functions:

```py
def func_1(arr, outlist):
    # do something with arr
    # store the value in result
    outlist.append(result)
    
def func_2(arr, outlist):
    # do something differnt with arr
    # store the value in result
    outlist.append(result)
```

P.S. This is a simpliified version of my [actual code](https://github.com/amkhrjee/algorithms-notebook/blob/main/Sorting.ipynb). I must take the entire array as input to the worker functions at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes run in different address spaces. So when `func_1` or `func_2` update lists `list_1` and `list_2` they are modifying copies of the lists that exist in their own respective address spaces; they are not updating the copies that exist in the main process.

There are several ways of handling this. One way is to create the lists in shared memory so that each child process is working on the same list as the one created by the main process. Another way is to have the child processes write their results to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. The third way, which is the simplest and what we will use, is to use a multiprocessing pool that internally uses a queue to return results.

You state that you want to "close by the end of each iteration." If by "close" you mean "terminate" then the code below will create and destroy the multiprocessing pool for each iteration. But this is very wasteful and I am not sure why you would want to do that.

Note: You should not use names such as `input` as variable name since `input` is the name of a built-in Python function. Also, `in`, which in your posted code you used as an argument name, is a reserved word in Python and cannot be used as a variable name.

```py
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def func_1(arr):
    t = time.process_time()
    sorted_arr = sorted(arr)
    return time.process_time() - t, sorted_arr

def func_2(arr):
    t = time.process_time()
    sorted_arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
    return time.process_time() - t, sorted_arr

def main():
    """
    # Use this order of the "for" and "with" blocks to
    # create the pool only once to avoid needless destruction
    # and re-creation of the pool:
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        for i in range(1, 6): # start from 1
    """
    for i in range(100_000, 1_100_000, 100_000): # start from 100_000
        with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
            arr = [random.randint(0, 1_000_000) for _ in range(i)]

            # Run these two operations in parallel:
            async_result1 = pool.apply_async(func_1, args=(arr,))
            async_result2 = pool.apply_async(func_2, args=(arr,))

            # Get the results and print:
            t1, list_1 = async_result1.get()
            t2, list_2 = async_result2.get()
            print(f'size = {i}, arr = {arr[0:3]} ... {arr[-3:]}')
            print(f'list_1 = {list_1[0:3]} ... {list_1[-3:]}, process time = {t1}')
            print(f'list_2 = {list_2[0:3]} ... {list_2[-3:]}, process time = {t2}')
            print()
        # The pool is terminated on exit from prior "with" block

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
size = 100000, arr = [963985, 885752, 398168] ... [346806, 931449, 731479]
list_1 = [3, 25, 39] ... [999975, 999981, 999992], process time = 0.015625
list_2 = [999992, 999981, 999975] ... [39, 25, 3], process time = 0.015625

size = 200000, arr = [998892, 442816, 338664] ... [914664, 469598, 779263]
list_1 = [2, 16, 17] ... [999978, 999982, 999984], process time = 0.03125
list_2 = [999984, 999982, 999978] ... [17, 16, 2], process time = 0.046875

size = 300000, arr = [329332, 623887, 967070] ... [848851, 937626, 842896]
list_1 = [3, 5, 7] ... [999994, 999994, 999995], process time = 0.078125
list_2 = [999995, 999994, 999994] ... [7, 5, 3], process time = 0.078125

size = 400000, arr = [94596, 348994, 79236] ... [135108, 522948, 124498]
list_1 = [0, 2, 8] ... [999997, 999998, 999999], process time = 0.09375
list_2 = [999999, 999998, 999997] ... [8, 2, 0], process time = 0.09375

size = 500000, arr = [597997, 143252, 612416] ... [271672, 825160, 351058]
list_1 = [3, 3, 5] ... [999992, 999997, 999997], process time = 0.140625
list_2 = [999997, 999997, 999992] ... [5, 3, 3], process time = 0.125

size = 600000, arr = [559728, 577812, 640277] ... [143838, 231247, 242004]
list_1 = [1, 3, 5] ... [999993, 999994, 1000000], process time = 0.171875
list_2 = [1000000, 999994, 999993] ... [5, 3, 1], process time = 0.171875

size = 700000, arr = [237665, 926271, 747910] ... [206456, 577997, 613106]
list_1 = [0, 2, 2] ... [999999, 1000000, 1000000], process time = 0.1875
list_2 = [1000000, 1000000, 999999] ... [2, 2, 0], process time = 0.21875

size = 800000, arr = [164147, 141817, 369944] ... [723224, 958884, 223842]
list_1 = [0, 1, 3] ... [999995, 999999, 999999], process time = 0.265625
list_2 = [999999, 999999, 999995] ... [3, 1, 0], process time = 0.28125

size = 900000, arr = [168167, 942110, 354510] ... [261892, 747797, 579109]
list_1 = [0, 1, 1] ... [999999, 1000000, 1000000], process time = 0.28125
list_2 = [1000000, 1000000, 999999] ... [1, 1, 0], process time = 0.28125

size = 1000000, arr = [720988, 161719, 803588] ... [710593, 309087, 699567]
list_1 = [0, 0, 3] ... [1000000, 1000000, 1000000], process time = 0.328125
list_2 = [1000000, 1000000, 1000000] ... [3, 0, 0], process time = 0.3437
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. What I basically want to do is to run a bunch of different sorting algorithms on the lists at each iteration and measure the time taken by each of the algorithms (this is what the worker functions return) in the lists (here `list_1` and `list_2`). So, naturally, I need to take the entire list as input in each of the iterations for each worker function. I will edit my question to add more clarity.

Comment: @AniruddhaMukherjee (1) You should specify up front in your question what your ultimate goal is; it wastes less time for *all* concerned. (2) If you are benchmarking different sort algorithms against varying sized input, why would you even need to be using multiprocessing to begin with? You will get more accurate timings if you run the sorts serially. (3) I have updated the answer to process entire lists and to return timings as well as the sorted results.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I apologize for the ambiguity of my question. I will keep your advice in mind. I have already done the benchmarking by serially running them. I was trying to do this for fun.

Answer (score 0):

If the CPython is not mandatory you can use python's multiprocessing library. Never the less I thing this method can work with CPython.

Create a Shared Queue

```
mp.Queue()
```

Initiate the processes in a pool passing the shared queue as an argument and your data

```
mp.Process(target= Your process, args= (Your shared Queue ,  Your Data ))
```

At the process side you should also create a reference to the shared queue in the **init** function

```
def __init__(self,queue_shared, data):
        self.queue_shared = queue_shared
```

[Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Try using Value and  Array objects as described in the documentation or Manager

Here is an example of your code using Array

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Array

list_1 = Array("i",range(10)) 
list_2 = Array("i", range(10))

def func_1(a, b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
            b[i] = -a[i]

def func_2(a, b):
    start = len(b) - 1
    for i in range(start, -1, -1):
        b[i] = random.randint(0,10) + a[i]


print("list_1 before", list_1[:])
print("list_2 before", list_2[:])

for input in range(1):
    lst = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10)]
    arr_1 = Array("i",lst  )
    arr_2 =  Array("i",lst  )

    print("arr_1 before", arr_1[:])
    print("arr_2 before", arr_2[:])

    proc_one = mp.Process(target=func_1, args=(arr_1, list_1))
    proc_two = mp.Process(target=func_2, args=(arr_2, list_2))
    
    proc_one.start()
    proc_two.start()
    
    proc_one.join()
    proc_two.join()
    
print("list_1 after", list_1[:])
print("list_2 after", list_2[:])
print("arr_1 after", arr_1[:])
print("arr_2 after", arr_2[:])
```

This should print something like that

```
list_1 before [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list_2 before [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr_1 before [9, 9, 1, 6, 3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0]
arr_2 before [9, 9, 1, 6, 3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0]
list_1 after [-9, -9, -1, -6, -3, 0, -1, -4, -4, 0]
list_2 after [12, 19, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 8, 6]
arr_1 after [9, 9, 1, 6, 3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0]
arr_2 after [9, 9, 1, 6, 3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0]
```

Comment: I *am* using the `multiprocessing` library. I think my question title is misleading. What I meant was that I am using the default CPython implementation instead of something like JPython.